# How to identify whether a TRP Spyre mechanical disc brake is the post-recall version?

Tags: disc-brake

For online (bargain) shoppers who face the risk of possibly buying old stock, are there any markings on the [post-recall TRP Spyre](https://www.bicycleretailer.com/recalls/2014/03/07/cpsc-issues-trp-brake-recall#.X-IIPNhKhhE) that could be used to clearly identify it as the new version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the article

*"Recalled calipers have a fastening screw with a hollow six-pointed star-shaped head with no markings on it and a 3 millimeter pad adjustment screw on the outward side."*

Modern TRP SPyre calipers have one 3 millimeter pad adjustment screw on both sides and no star-shaped head.

From your article:
[image]

From modern shops:
[image]